# Google Spreadsheet: Script to pick the right values from data which is html-imported and never in the right order

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following problem I can't solve:

There is data of a measuring station for water quality available online (https://hamburg.de/clp/hu/fischerhof/clp1/). It updates every day, but the data is nowhere stored or put into a chart. So my play was to have a script which imports the data automatically. Functions in my spreadsheet would do the rest and put e.g. the water temperature in a chart. So far so good, I found all the scripts and work arounds here.

Then I discovered a problem I can't solve: When the data is uploaded on the website, it is not in the same order. Sometimes water temperature is in the first row, sometimes in the last, sometimes anywhere between. This messes all my data up, as I use a function which filters e.g. every 12-th row, to filter all the water temperature values out and make a chart out of it. When that position changed because of the import, I get wrong values.

Here is my setup so far:

[I import the data into Sheet 1 with a script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwOhq.png)

[This script also gathers the data in Sheet 2, where I filter the Water temp values on the right side, the red value shows the problem I mentioned aboth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNBfo.png)

Have you guys an idea how I can solve this problem? It's my first "project" of this kind, it was really fun until I discovered the problem, but I would really love to make it work!

Comment: Do you know how to write python? Because, you can write a python script where you can scrape the data from the web and then export a csv or excel file while properly processing the data based on the "Merkmal" keys. This will ensure proper values every day.

Comment: But if you want to do it in excel sheet, then you can select and update the value of water temperature based on the condition of "Merkmal" == "Wassertemperatur" instead of selecting based on cell number.

Comment: Hi @AbdullahAlNahid, thanks for your comment! I only can work with Google SpreadSheet. Could you give me more details on the "Merkmal" approach? I can't find the right function for it. Feel free to use english terms only as I use Google in english language. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am talking about putting "hardcoded value" during filtering like explained here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function

Comment: You disappeared @RudolfHinkler When you come back read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
=QUERY(A2:C40,"select A, C where B matches 'Wassertemperatur' 
                 label A 'date', C 'Watertemp.'",1)
```

[image]